# Display duration of outlook appointment?

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting

I am unable to display the duration of each appointment in my list box.  I'm trying to print in the listbox 11:30; (60) B/H or 11:30-12:30; B/H, however unsure of how to do this, please may someone help?

I have tried `$Duration` and `$._Duration`, putting them between `"[...]Start.ToString('HH:mm'), $_.Subject } " 'HH:mm'` and `$_. subject` however these haven't been successful

```
#listbox for calendar entry
$Listboxcal= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$Listboxcal.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,55) 
$Listboxcal.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,270) 
$Listboxcal.Height = 150

add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.oldefaultfolders?view=outlook-pia
# Calendar = olFolderCalendar = 9
$calendar = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(9)
# get today's calendar items!
 $cItems = $calendar.Items | Where-Object {$_.Start -ge $(Get-Date $StrCaldate) -and $_.Start -le $(Get-Date $StrCaldate).AddDays(1)} |Sort-Object -Property Start | foreach { "{0}; {1}" -f $_.Start.ToString('HH:mm'), $_.Subject } 
ForEach ($calendars in $cItems) {[void]$Listboxcal.Items.Add($calendars)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The calendar appointments have a duration property.  You just need to add that to the `$cItems` variable

```
$cItems = $calendar.Items | Where-Object {$_.Start -ge $(Get-Date $StrCaldate) -and $_.Start -le $(Get-Date $StrCaldate).AddDays(1)} |Sort-Object -Property Start | foreach { "{0}; ({1}) {2}" -f $_.Start.ToString('HH:mm'), $_.Duration, $_.Subject }
```

When I run this on my own calendar, I get the following:

`16:30; (60) Appointment 1
18:30; (120) Appointment 2`

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me with the Duration property:

```
$calendar.Items | Select -First 1 | %{ $_.StartUTC.Tostring("hh:mm") `
+ "; (" + $_.Duration + ") " + $_.Subject}
```